# Regex to change quotation mark conflict

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a PHP regex to filter my content on WordPress. I would like to transform quotation marks `" "` like that `« »` with non-breaking space.

I also use Timber (TWIG) filter to achieve this.

The problem is that this filter also changes `url tags` and `image tags`.

**Example :**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">My link</a>

<a href=« http://www.example.com »>My link</a>
```

What could I add in my regex to avoid this? Can I have some help please.

### functions.php

```
public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
        $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extension_StringLoader() );
        $twig->addFilter( new Timber\Twig_Filter( 'changemarks', 'changemarks' ) );
        return $twig;
    }

function changemarks( $text ) {
    $regex = '/"(.*?)"/';
    $subst = '«&#8239;$1&#8239;»';
    $result = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $text);

    return $result;
}
```

### single.twig

```
{{ post.content|changemarks }}
```

Comment: Did you tried to only format the content displayed instead of all the DOM ?... Seems a strange design pattern

Comment: Well. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to make regular expression in html my solution is just select the string by make some space before and after `"` for text

```
    $regex = '/ "(.+?)" /';
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works very well. What the difference between (.+?) and (.*?) ?

Comment: @Jandon `(.*?)` will match whatever even empty but `(.+?)` should be not empty, one or more. For more details https://www.regular-expressions.info/